# How to specify HashMapping when using Hocon

Tags: f#, akka.net, hocon

Given the `HOCON` below for a `consitent-hashing-pool`router, how do I specify the hashMapping.

```
    akka {
      actor {
        serializers {
          wire = "Akka.Serialization.WireSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Wire"
        }
        serialization-bindings {
          "System.Object" = wire
        }
        deployment {
          /data-collector {
            router = consistent-hashing-pool
            nr-of-instances = 10
          }
        }
      }
      loggers = ["Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.Logger.NLog"]
    }
```

Given

```
let config = Configuration.load()
let systemName = config.GetString("app-config.actorsystem", "my-system")
let system = System.create systemName config
let collectorRouter = 
  let hashMapping (msg:obj) =
    match msg with
    | :? Message as msg ->
        match msg with
        | Parse (_, req) -> req.uniqueId |> box
    | _ -> "-" |> box
  ConsistentHashingPool (10, ConsistentHashMapping hashMapping)
let dataCollectorProps = 
  { props (dataCollector settings.collector) with
      Router = Some (collectorRouter :> RouterConfig)} //(FromConfig.Instance.WithFallback collectorRouter)
let test = spawn system "data-collector" <| dataCollectorProps
```

`Router = Some (collectorRouter :> RouterConfig)` work

`Router = Some (FromConfig.Instance.WithFallback collectorRouter)` doesn't

What is the correct way to specify the hashMapping function?

**Edit 1**
The warning from the console is

`Akka.Routing.ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic|Message [Message] must be handled by hashMapping, or implement [IConsistentHashable] or be wrapped in [ConsistentHashableEnvelope]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [three ways of specifying the hash key](http://getakka.net/docs/Routing#consistenthash). My favourite is to implement `IConsistentHashable` and return the key (based on some properties of the message) from the `ConsistentHashKey` property.

Example excerpt from [my Consistent Hashing article](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/consistent-hashing-in-akka-net/) (in C#; sorry I don't know F#):

```cs
public class CurrencyPriceChangeMessage : IConsistentHashable
{
    public string CurrencyPair { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }

    public object ConsistentHashKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CurrencyPair;
        }
    }
```

The hash key will be used to route messages with the same key always to the same routee.

Comment: I changed the `nr-of-instances` to 3 in hocon and the router had three routees. The hashing also worked. Is it the case that when the router is defined in both code and hocon, it picks the one from hocon and suppliments it with the config from code?

Comment: As far as I know, when a setting is defined in both code and HOCON, the HOCON one takes precedence.